# При обучение модели через Object detection api получаю ошибку No module named 'official.modeling.optimization'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

При попытке обучить модель, выскакивает ошибка

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official.modeling.optimization'
```

При это в PYTHONPATH путь к models,models\research,model\slim есть
[image: PYTHONPATH]
[image: Путь к библиотеке]
, сам Object detection установил и тестовый запуск был успешным (который python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py)
[image: Вывод после model_builder_tf2_test]

python 3.7
tensorflow = 2.2
keras = 2.3.1
Заранее обученная модель - http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz

Простите если мало или много информации, первый раз задаю тут вопрос)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась установкой python версии 3.9 и tf 2.5.